# Получить цену на вещь CS:GO php

Tags: php, curl, steam-web-api

День добрый, собственно столкнулся с такой проблемой. У Steam есть апи, с помощью которой можно получать цену на ту или иную вещь. Беда в том что на эту апи можно посылать ограниченное число запросов. И в итоге у меня цена вещи на сайте показывает:0 . Я пошел дальше, подумал мб если парсить цены прям с сайта, а не с апи, такого лимита нету. Ну и в итоге он там тоже есть, не больше там 20 запросов за 2 часа вроде как. Собственно сам вопрос, може кто-нибудь знает обход данной проблемы? или есть альтернативные аппи без ограничений.

Comment: Если бы не было ограничений, то можно было отличненько так организовать атаку на них. Вы думаете они этого хотели бы? Вряд ли. Отсюда и ограничения.

Comment: Ну а что тогда делать то? вон всякие рулетки ксго как-то же работают

Comment: @Corle рулетки работают иначе, а цены проставляются не в `live` режиме, а допустим раз в день (или пол дня). И они не совсем требовательны к API стима

Comment: Единственный нормальный выход, как написал Василий, проходиться по списку предметов, упираясь в лимиты. Получится, что один и тот же предмет вы будете проверять раз в несколько дней. Для более "горячих" предметов можете сделать так, чтобы они проверялись чаще других. Как вариант еще делать запросы через прокси и зарегистрировать несколько ключей доступа (если они нужны для чтения торговой площадки). Также, может быть, существуют сервисы с API, предоставляющие ту же информацию, но платно и без таких жестких лимитов.

Comment: А зачем вообще долбить каждый раз? Ну и качайте весь список к себе и по мере необходимости, обновляйте. не вижу сложности.

Comment: Комментарии оставлять не могу, поэтому напишу в ответе.
Рулетки, обменники и т.п. чаще всего берут цены не напрямую со стима, а с steamanalyst, у них вроде и api свой есть, так что попробуй в эту сторону покопать.

Answer (score 1):

альтернативы есть , но придется прогонять цикл , и присваивать предмету цену по его имени , моя реализация но nodejs выглядит так

```
    //парсинг цены итемов
var g_PricesUpdate = 300; // интервал в секундах
var prices;
function getprices(){
   request('https://api.csgofast.com/price/all', function(error, response, body) {
       prices = JSON.parse(body);
       if(response.statusCode != 200) {
           logger.info("Не могу загрузить цены с сайта. Юзаю Файл.");
           if(fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt')){
               prices = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt'));
               logger.info('Старые Цены Загружены!');
           }
       } else {
           fs.writeFileSync('prices.txt', body);
           logger.info('Цены Успешно Обновлены!');
       }
   });
}
setInterval(function(){getprices();},g_PricesUpdate*1000);
getprices();
```

на php этот код переписать не составит труда , ключевая информация нужная вам это ссылка в этой функции